# How to store recorded audio in a location

Tags: javascript

How to send audio (blob) in a directory ie. /uploads/audio/audio.wav

Audio file is recorded using recorder.js

```
function saveRecording() {
    console.log("Saving audio...");

    //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings
    stop.disabled = true;
    record.disabled = true;
    listening.disabled = true;
    save.disabled = false;

    //tell the recorder to stop the recording
    rec.stop();

    //stop microphone access
  gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

    //create the wav blob and pass it on to createDownloadLink
    rec.exportWAV(sendData);

    rec.clear();
}

function sendData(blob) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    //add controls to the <audio> element
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    //link the a element to the blob
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'audio-' + Date.now() + '.wav';
    link.innerHTML = link.download;
    //add the new audio and a elements to the li element
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(link);
    //add the li element to the ordered list
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

How to store audio.wav in another directory /uploads/audio/audio.wav

Comment: You can't: JS do not have access to the local directory, if what you want to achieve is to force it to download to a specific location. That restriction is in place for security reasons: you wouldn't want a website to overwrite your OS files, do you?

Comment: Is there any solution? in node js application record audio using recorder.js and then upload to a directory say /uploads/audios/filename.wav

Comment: If you mean you want to save it to the server (not the user's device) then you can send the data to the server using an AJAX request

Comment: @ADyson can you please help me with code?... thanks

Comment: Have you ever done an AJAX request before? If not then it would make sense to get the idea of the basics from tutorials / documentation etc first, then try something for yourself. And also learn how to debug the request using your browser's developer tools. These are extremely valuable skills for the future. If you get stuck then post the code here along with any errors etc. Then I can help you on specifics rather than teaching you things you could already learn in a tutorial

Comment: P.s. the modern way to make an AJAX request is using the Fetch API, so find tutorials etc which refer to that and not older technology